# Out of range Exception . Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection. Parameter name: index

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I am unable to resolve this error. i am filtering datagridview with text box via text changed event. After a filtered results are shown in datagridview i am adding image looks like button to image column. The reason for programmatically adding button is, i have dark and light theme in my application and i have to set dark button image if dark theme is set other wise light button image.

The exception isn't raising all the time but very often specially when i'am adding and removing text to textbox faster.

Exception is raising at these lines of code in the function AddButtonToGrid()

```
((DataGridViewImageCell)DataGridViewAllMusic.Rows[row].Cells[1]).Value = Properties.Resources.DarkPLPS;

((DataGridViewImageCell)DataGridViewAllMusic.Rows[row].Cells[1]).Value = Properties.Resources.LightPLPS;
```

**Exception Details :**

```
System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException HResult=0x80131502 Message=Index was out of range. 
   Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
Parameter name: index
  Source=mscorlib
  StackTrace:
   at System.ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentOutOfRangeException(ExceptionArgument argument, ExceptionResource resource)
   at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewRowCollection.get_Item(Int32 index)
   at MY_Player.Forms.MainForm.<AddButtonToGrid>b__29_0() in C:\Users\HP\Desktop\
Player\Forms\MainForm.cs:line 290
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
```

My Code:

TextboxSearch_TextChanged

```
        private void TextboxSearch_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                if (TextboxSearch.Text != "" && DataGridViewAllMusic.DataSource != null)
                {
                    DataGridViewAllMusic.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
                    {
                        this.DataGridViewAllMusic.SelectionChanged -= new EventHandler(DataGridViewAllMusic_SelectionChanged);
                        (DataGridViewAllMusic.DataSource as DataTable).DefaultView.RowFilter = string.Format("Value LIKE '{0}%' or Artist LIKE '{1}%' or Album LIKE '{2}%' or Comments LIKE '{3}%' ",
                        TextboxSearch.Text, TextboxSearch.Text, TextboxSearch.Text, TextboxSearch.Text);

                        AddButtonToGrid();
                        this.DataGridViewAllMusic.SelectionChanged += new EventHandler(DataGridViewAllMusic_SelectionChanged);
                    });
                }
                else
                {
                    if (DataGridViewAllMusic.DataSource != null)
                    {
                        DataGridViewAllMusic.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
                        {
                            this.DataGridViewAllMusic.SelectionChanged -= new EventHandler(DataGridViewAllMusic_SelectionChanged);
                            (DataGridViewAllMusic.DataSource as DataTable).DefaultView.RowFilter = null;
                            AddButtonToGrid();
                            this.DataGridViewAllMusic.SelectionChanged += new EventHandler(DataGridViewAllMusic_SelectionChanged);  
                        });
                    }
                }
            }
            catch
            {

            }
        }
```

AddButtonToGrid()

```
        private async  void AddButtonToGrid()
        {
            await Task.Run(() =>
            {
                if (DataGridViewAllMusic.Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                    if (DarkMode)
                    {
                        DataGridViewAllMusic.RowHeadersWidthSizeMode = DataGridViewRowHeadersWidthSizeMode.DisableResizing;
                        DataGridViewAllMusic.RowHeadersVisible = false;
                        for (int row = 0; row <= DataGridViewAllMusic.Rows.Count - 1; row++)
                        {
                            ((DataGridViewImageCell)DataGridViewAllMusic.Rows[row].Cells[1]).Value = Properties.Resources.DarkPLPS;
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        DataGridViewAllMusic.RowHeadersWidthSizeMode = DataGridViewRowHeadersWidthSizeMode.DisableResizing;
                        DataGridViewAllMusic.RowHeadersVisible = false;

                        for (int row = 0; row <= DataGridViewAllMusic.Rows.Count - 1; row++)
                        {
                            ((DataGridViewImageCell)DataGridViewAllMusic.Rows[row].Cells[1]).Value = Properties.Resources.LightPLPS;
                        }
                    }
                }

            }).ConfigureAwait(false);
        }
```

Comment: All the pseudo-asynchronous code you have there is wrong; IMO debugging it - as presented - is probably useless. -- Note that setting `CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = false` just removes the notification, not the problems that the notification warns you about.

Comment: i have made  adding button function asynchronous for large data. when there is more than 5k rows in datagridview the search function gets slowed just because after every letter types the function AddButtontoGrid is being called.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to execute your UI code in multiple threads.

Just don't.

You should manipulate UI elements form main thread only. So for your code just remove `await Task.Run(() =>` and if your `TextboxSearch_TextChanged` method is actually called only by the event you do not need the `Invoke` call either. UI events are executed on main thread. Also if you have `async` method take good care to `await` them whenever possible otherwise you are creating hard to debug problems.

If you want to experiment with multithreading in your application you should split it into areas of concern. UI would be one and data manipulation could be other. There are patterns and frameworks out there that facilitate separation of concerns.